# Recursive calls in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: recursion, pentaho, kettle

Is it possible for a step or transformation in Pentaho Data Integration to call itself, passing the results of the previous call as parameters/variables?

My first thought was to create a loop in a transformation, but they don't seem to be allowed...

Comment: It just say as a warning. I created loop and it worked fine in Pentaho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to do this at the transformation level then take a look at the sub mapping step.

Of course, there is no loops as you describe, but you can always simulate one with a generate rows.

Alternatively you'd be best to ask this question on the Kettle forums (forums.pentaho.org) as there are very few kettle dev folk on here.

Comment: +1 I Went with generate rows + "execute for each row" applied to a sub-job (as per the samples). Thanks for the suggestion!